# Allowing access to local SQL Server from local apps

Tags: connection, sql-server

On a brand new system (Win 10 in this case but hopefully not system specific), I've installed latest SQL Server and now I want to connect to it from local apps.

What steps must be taken to allow other apps on my PC to connect to a database?

So far I have:

- Ensured the `SQL Server` service is running.
- Ensured port `1433` is open in Inbound firewall rules.

These are both well documented elsewhere.

After installing telnet:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

I still get:

```
C:\Users\Me>telnet localhost 1433
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed
```

This one always seems to take me so long to track down as it can be months/years between attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the one I always seem to miss. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850073/823393) for instructions. It is the setting of the IPALL *TCP Dynamic Ports* value to `0` (it then assigns its own).

> If your setup has the protocol *Listen All* value at **Yes** set the *TCP Dynamic Ports* value to `0`.